# Map a domain to my localhost

Tags: ios, macos, host, domain-name

I ran the command `sudo nano /etc/host` to edit the hosts file, and added `test.com` next to `127.0.0.1`. Then I launched wamp, but now when I open test.com, it doesn't go to my localhost. What's wrong?

```
127.0.0.1 test.com
```

Comment: Corrected grammar and added details to improve clarity

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the recent history of your browser.